# Retrieving set of instances via owl:sameAs on Ontotext GraphDB

Tags: sparql, owl, inference, graphdb, knowledge-graph

Assuming we have the following set of facts loaded on Ontotext GraphDB:

```
@prefix : <http://www.example.org#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

:bbq_sauce a :Ingredient ;
           :hasBrand :ispc .
:strawberry a :Ingredient ;
            :hasBrand :driscolls .
:blueberry a :Ingredient ;
           :hasBrand :driscolls .
:ispc a :Brand ;
      owl:sameAs :driscolls .
:driscolls a :Brand ;
           owl:sameAs :ispc .
```

Which are visually illustrated by the following diagram:
[image]

I would like the following SPARQL query to retrieve all the brands for `:strawberry`, explicit and implicit:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.example.org#>
SELECT ?brand WHERE {
    :strawberry :hasBrand ?brand .
}
```

Running the query on GraphDB's SPARQL tab on the UI, I only retrieve the `driscolls` brand that is explicitly stated in the knowledge graph. How can I also retrieve the other brands that are declared as the same with `driscolls` via `owl:sameAs`? Note that the inference functionalities are activated in the UI (icons on the right hand side of the screenshot below):[image]

Comment: *"Note that the inference functionalities are activated in the UI"* - which one exactly? ( your image is just an icon)

Comment: @UninformedUser I was referring to the SPARQL tab on the GraphDB UI. I replaced the last figure to make it more informative.

Comment: @StratosK Which ruleset you have used when creating your repository? The default `RDFSPlus` or RDFS do not have explicit rules to handle `owl:sameAs` or alternatively you may uncheck the `disable owl:sameAs` option on repository creation page to enable those.

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov that's an excellent point which I missed in the first place. Indeed I had used the default option `RDFSPlus`. Changing it to `OWL Horst` allows the repository to behave as expected. Many thanks for pointing this out! I will edit my original post.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Damyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9729571/damyan-ognyanov) in the comments section, in order to enable the `owl:sameAs` capability, one has to create a repository with the respective ruleset in the first place. Choosing `OWL-Horst` (or, I guess, any of the available OWL variants) will do the job - see figure below:

[image]